# Filtering dataframe column elements by different dtypes (as contain INT and STR to make entire column and Object)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a column that currently has the dtype of Object. This is because 0.2% of the elements in that column are stings, while the remaining 99.8% are integers. How can I filter the dataframe column by dtype?

(I have found that df.select_dtypes(include='bool') would return any column in the df that has a bool but my issue is that a single column is identified with dtype=Object, because it's made up of INT and STR.)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2], ['three']], columns=['A'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are mixed numeric and strings is possible test `type`s - by `isinstance`:

```
m = df['A'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int))
print (m)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Or by `type`:

```
m = df['A'].apply(type) == int
print (m)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

If there are all strings - also numeric use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with convert to numeric if possible, else missing values, so possible test by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')
m = df['A'].notna()
```

And last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[m]
print (df)
   A
0  1
1  2
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael this works however I was hoping to filter the strings 'in-situ' so that I could identify them and then update/ replace one at a time to the max integer +1 (+2, +3, +4). Your method would simply remove the strings for good.

Comment: @tristar8 - What is expected output?

Comment: Building on what you've suggested I've come up with this...
`lst_str =[]
lst_int = []
for i in df_working['SKU']:
    if type(pd.to_numeric(i, errors='ignore')) == str:
        lst_str.append(i)
    if type(pd.to_numeric(i, errors='ignore')) == int:
        lst_int.append(i)`

Comment: @tristar8 - Is possible use `lst_str =[] 
lst_int = [] 
for i in df_working['SKU']]: 
    if type(i) == str: 
        lst_str.append(i) 
    if type(i) == int: 
        lst_int.append(i) ` ?